# Как расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: и, синтаксис, пунктуация

**Вирус этот слабо задевает носоглотку(?) поэтому человек не чихает(?) и окружающие не заражаются.**

Понятно, что это сложное предложение, состоящее из трёх простых, с бессоюзной и союзной сочинительной связями. На месте первого "?" можно поставить запятую или тире. А вот нужен ли знак  после "чихает"? Можно ли здесь рассматривать части, соединенные союзом "и", как однородные? Или же союз "и" соединяет бессоюзное и простое, то есть запятая обязательна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно предложить следующее оформление предложения:"Вирус этот слабо задевает носоглотку, поэтому человек не чихает и окружающие не заражаются".

Это, действительно, предложение с бессоюзной и союзной сочинительной связью. ПОЭТОМУ - местоименное наречие, его называют дополнительным структурным элементом, помогающим выразить семантику отношений между простыми предложениями  в БСП ( данном случае причинно-следственные отношения).

(1) При наличии наречия ПОЭТОМУ мы имеем дополнительное значение пояснения-комментария, поэтому тире здесь не ставится, но можно поставить двоеточие или запятую. Остановимся на запятой, которая не требует увеличенной предупредительной паузы.

(2) Лучше считать, что наречие ПОЭТОМУ относится к ССП и является общим элементом, из чего следует, что запятая перед И не ставится.

Таким образом,  предложение состоит из двух частей, семантически выражающих значение "причина - следствие", причем следствием являются оба простых предложений, которые интонационно составляют одну фразу.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, здесь нет бессоюзной связи, а только союзная подчинительная и сочинительная (поэтому - союзное слово, выраженное местоименным наречием). На месте первого (?) можно поставить только запятую. Во-вторых, между частями, соединенными сочинительным союзом "и", запятая не нужна по двум причинам: с одной стороны, это однородные придаточные, а с другой, если Вас смущает некоторая смысловая несоотнесенность вируса в носоглотке и заражения окружающих, то основанием для отсутствия запятой служит общий второстепенный член "поэтому".

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ, но согласиться с Вами не могу. "Поэтому" - указательное наречие, а союзные слова - это  наречия (или местоимения) относительные. Кроме того, в придаточном следствия по определению средством связи может быть только союз «так что». Что касается второй запятой, то я тоже её не поставила бы, хотя "поэтому" можно здесь рассматривать и как общий второстепенный член, и как обстоятельство только для одной части (поэтому человек не чихает).

Comment: "Поэтому" здесь союзное слово (в значении "вследствие этого, потому": Стало темно, поэтому зажгли лампу. ). Значение местоименного наречия "поэтому" - "по этой причине, вот почему": Опоздал из-за пурги? - Да, поэтому. И здесь действительно однородные придаточные.

Answer (score 0):

Вирус этот слабо задевает носоглотку, поэтому человек не чихает, и окружающие не заражаются.

Я думаю, что вот так нужно расставить знаки препинания.

Перед **поэтому** запятая, я думаю, понятна. А затем идут два простых предложения, в которых две грамматические основы: [человек не чихает] и [окружающие не заражаются]. Следовательно, сочинительный союз **и**, соединяющий два простых предложения в составе сложных, должен быть выделен запятой. Что касается **поэтому**, то тут подчинительный союз.

Думаю, мой вариант правильный.

Comment: Зря Вы так думаете)))  Подчинительным союзом у Вас каким-то мистическим образом стало указательное местоименное наречие! Это новое слово в языкознании! Поздравляю с открытием, коллега)

Comment: При чем тут указательное наречие?

Comment: Попробуем доказать, что ПОЭТОМУ не является союзом. У союза есть два значения: семантическое и грамматическое, а вот у местоименного наречия ПОЭТОМУ своего грамматического значения нет: оно не участвует в построении структуры предложений, а только проясняется смысловые отношения "причина-следствие". В СПП с придаточным следствия используется союз ТАК ЧТО, но в данном случае он семантически не очень точен. В то же время общую структуру предложения и отсутствие запятой перед И он может прояснить:"Вирус этот слабо задевает носоглотку, так что человек не чихает и окружающие не заражаются".

Answer (score 0):

ПОЭТОМУ.

I. местоим. нареч.

По этой причине, вот почему. Опоздал из-за пурги? - Да, поэтому.

II. союзное слово

Вследствие этого, потому. Стало темно, п. зажгли лампу. Уже поздно, а п. поторопись. Неудачник, п. и озлоблен.